# Use group value meeting criteria as new group identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset with an identifier column for each group and values for each instance in the group. I'd like to change the identifier for each group to instead be a row value by a certain criteria, in this case let's say the row value that starts with `A` **(only instance one per group)**. How can I transform the data to create such a new identifier?

Code to create sample data

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    Val VARCHAR(3),
    ID INT
)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('ABC', 1);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('DEF', 1);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('GHI', 1);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('JKL', 1);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('MNO', 2);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('ADE', 2);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('PQR', 2);
```

The desired result I'd like to have with the `A%` instance value per group as a column.

```
ABC,1,ABC
DEF,1,ABC
GHI,1,ABC
JKL,1,ABC
MNO,2,ADE
ADE,2,ADE
PQR,2,ADE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than 2 scans, you can use a window function:

```
SELECT Val,
       ID,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Val LIKE 'A%' THEN Val END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Val2
FROM @Test;
```

If you don't want `NULL` when you don't have a row starting with `A`, just use `Val` instead of the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using the following logic

```
WITH CTE_1 AS (
    SELECT ID,VAL FROM @Test WHERE Val like 'A%')
SELECT T1.*,CTE_1.Val FROM @Test T1 
INNER JOIN CTE_1 
ON T1.ID = CTE_1.ID
```

OR

```
SELECT Val, ID, 
(SELECT TOP 1 Val FROM @Test T2 WHERE T2.Val like 'A%' AND T2.ID = T1.ID) as Val2
FROM @Test T1
```

OR

```
SELECT T1.*,CTE_1.Val 
FROM @Test T1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ID,VAL FROM @Test WHERE Val like 'A%') as CTE_1 
ON T1.ID = CTE_1.ID
```

*Result*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well using inner select in select statment is really bad for performance.

Instead Use left join.

```
select t1.Val, t1.ID , t.Val as val2
from @Test t1
left join @Test t on t1.ID = t.ID and t.Val like 'A%'
```